# SharedPreferences is not updating its value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Below is a snippet of code that i use in my save settings function (DialogFragment):

```
String orderBy = mOrderBySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String search = mSearchEditText.getText().toString().trim();

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putString(InventoryPreferences.ORDER_BY, orderBy);
editor.putString(InventoryPreferences.SEARCH_TERM, search);
editor.apply();
```

I then retrieve that data with the following (Activity):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String orderBy = sharedPrefs.getString(InventoryPreferences.ORDER_BY, "name ASC");
String searchTerm = sharedPrefs.getString(
                InventoryPreferences.SEARCH_TERM,"").trim();
```

These are my keys:

```
public static final String ORDER_BY = "orderBy";
public static final String SEARCH_TERM = "search";
```

Is there any reason as to why it wouldn't update the values when the key is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

is not

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Use the second line in both methods.

From the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   **private to this activity**

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! Will put as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different methods to get access to a `SharedPreferences` file.

The first time using `getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` you are calling Activity's [`getPreferences(int mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)) which returns a SharedPreferences object which is supposed to be private to the activity which requests it. The name of the preferences file this SharedPreferences object points to is CLASS_NAME.xml

The second time using [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context))
returns a SharedPreferences object which is supposed to be available and useful for the entire application. The name of the preferences file this SharedPreferences object points to is PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml.

So your problem is that you are using one file to write the preferences to and another to read them. Try using the more global thinking `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` to store preferences that relate to the entire application, and only use `Activity.getPreferences(int mode)` for preferences that only relate to a specific activity. (And then also remember to use the appropriate methods to retrieve them)

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreferenceManager` to access SharedPreference.

Answer (score -1):

Your code for updating preference value is correct.

Consider verifying that the values in input controls really changed
and verify, that the application has permission to write preferences.